# Snowflake Stitch connection throws 403 error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-pipeline, snowflake-connector, stitch

I’m trying to connect snowflake with stitch, I’m trying to get google sheets data to snowflake using stitch.
I’ve strictly followed documentation but the connection exits with 403
error. Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: This is not enough to understand why you're getting 403. Is there any error message? Are you able at least to connect to Snowflake? Are you using the proper role?

Comment: a couple of reasons for 403 are listed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/search.html#q=403&t=All&sort=relevancy

Comment: Issue is fixed. @sergiu- 403 error was caused because I made a new user to access the db, but user permissions were not granted.

Comment: @Fkyani - in snowflake documentation it mentions to use account as abcde.snowflakecomputing.com. In my case it did not work. I had to mention the region & whitelist IPs(stitch IPs & my local IP)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. @sergiu- 403 error was caused because I made a new user to access the db, but user permissions were not granted. Stitch documentation is incomplete in this regard.